# A doubt on conservation of linear momentum

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum

Please look at the image given below.[image]

Since the human of mass 'm' is dropped onto the car under the influence of gravity and since the dashed line does not include the earth how is momentum conserved as gravity is now an external force on the system?

P.S:the answer key in my book says that momentum is conserved so can someone give an explanation as to why this is?

Also since the momentum has to be conserved does it mean the car is moving with constant velocity(Fnet=0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. There is an external force on the system you have identified, which is gravity. As this force acts purely in the y - direction, the *y - component* of linear momentum is not conserved.

Notice that there are no external forces in the x - direction. The only force in the horizontal direction is possibly friction between the man's feet and the car, but this is internal to the system. Hence, the *x - component* of linear momentum is conserved. This can be mathematically written as:

$$ \Delta p_x = 0 \rightarrow m_{car}(v_{xi}) + 0 = (m_{car} + m_{man})v_{xf}$$

assuming the man sticks to the car on contact.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok I understood that in the y-direction it isn't conserved but in the x direction the force to drive the car must be equal to frictional force on it so that fnet=0.Am I right?

Comment: Gravity is not the only force acting along the y axis. The net force along the y axis is zero. If gravity is external to the system so is the normal force from the ground.

Comment: @nasu, The man does not experience a normal force while in the air.

Comment: @AJknight, Yes I assumed friction was absent. If you include the surface in the system then both friction and the driving force are internal to the system (unless the car is being pushed by an external force), so you can still use the conservation principle in the x direction.

Comment: @Cross, So even if I assumed no friction of any kind and if I gave the car a force initially it would continue moving with that velocity until an external force is applied according to Newton's first law or if I choose to include friction then I would have to apply a constant force equal and opposite to friction force to make fnet=0 and make it move with constant velocity and conserve momentum.Am I right?

Comment: Yep, but if the force is constant, once the man lands on the car, the frictional force will exceed the driving force (increased normal force) and then $F_{net} = 0$ doesn't hold. So the conservation of momentum will hold only before and _just_ after the man lands on the car. If there is no friction and driving force, everything you've said holds good.

Answer (score 0):

Momentum is the quantity which has magnitude as well as direction, so the direction has the significance equal to it's magnitude.

So, if there is momentum in $y$ then it won't disturb the momentum in the $x$ direction then momentum of man in $y$ direction will disappear and get converted into vibration of molecules of the cart and in severe cases the the molecules of the ground as well in $y$ direction only. they won't oscillate in $x$ direction (if inelastic collision that means no bouncing) so after this scenario the forces will be balanced i.e normal and gravity along $y$ axis and if already there is no acceleration along the $x$ direction or velocity is constant that means the momentum is going to remain constant so the velocity of cart in the $x$ direction is going to decrease with addition of the mass of the man to the cart.

Hope it helps